# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Error

Tags: python, sqlite

keep getting this error "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:"

```py
import _sqlite3

connection = _sqlite3.connect("IDTag.db")

IdSql = connection.cursor()

IDs = input('What is your ID?')

names = input("What is your name?")

surnames = input("What is your Surname?")

SqlIN= 'INSERT INTO idtags (ID,Name,Surname) VALUES ('+ IDs + ','+ names + ','+ surnames + ');'
print(SqlIN)
IdSql.execute(SqlIN)
```

This is the result when i execute the .py

```py
What is your ID?2
What is your name?jon
What is your Surname?harp
INSERT INTO idtags (ID,Name,Surname) VALUES (2,jon,harp);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mrfluffy/data/IdReader.py", line 15, in <module>
    IdSql.execute(SqlIN)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: jon
```

anyon have any idea on what is could be thanks in advance

Comment: What is `_sqlite3`? Also, you shouldn't be using string concatenation for queries anyway since it's an injection risk.

Comment: `SqlIN= 'INSERT INTO idtags (ID,Name,Surname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` then `IdSql.execute(SqlIN, (IDs, names, surnames))`

Comment: `jon` and `harp` are clearly meant to be strings, so they should be enclosed in single quotes.  But because they're not, the db assumes they are references to other columns.

Comment: They shouldn't be enclosed in anything, the OP should be using the library properly and using placeholders. Stop with the string formatting or concatenation already. The SQL tags are becoming beyond a joke over this kind of thing; the problems wouldn't arise if people followed basic guides and others stopped trying to aid in a flawed approach

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for the help sorry for trubeling you but i do appritiate the awnser

Comment: I was getting more frustrated by the suggestions of others. Please be sure to use parameterized queries in future to avoid SQL Injection. It also fixes your issue at the same time.

Comment: it did work thanks for the help means a lot